# Blured tiles while loading map

Tags: openlayers

It might be a stupid question but I need to ask it. On the latest version of OpenLayers which is using OSM tiles, when you are quickly zooming map the tiles which are not loaded yet gets blurry:

[image]

On very, very old OpenLayers 2 it was looking like this:

[image]

I like the new behaviour a lot but one of the customers is asking me if there is a way to make it as it was before? He doesn't like those blurred tiles but prefers white squares. I also remember that in the past there was some kind of "x" icon in one of the tiles squares when they have not been loaded.

Bing tiles load fast and there is no problems but OSM is working slowly those days.

Comment: Setting `useInterimTilesOnError: false` and `preload: Infinity` in the layer options might help, or use a solution such as https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/261269/hide-old-tiles-while-loading-new-ones-when-zooming-in-openlayers

Comment: I tested the solution from the link and it seems to do what I've been looking for. Thanks @Mike!